# How do i get along with this webapi project error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi

Im making a WebApi core project for school and everything seemed fine until i decided to start up the project to test it. When I start it up this  error appears https://imgbbb.com/images/2020/01/16/error.png

Here's everything that my project consists of:

[image: project tree]

And here's the controller code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using webapi3.Models;
using webapi3.Models.Repository;
using RouteAttribute = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute;

namespace webapi3.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IDataRepository<Employee> _dataRepository;

        public EmployeeController(IDataRepository<Employee> dataRepository)
        {
            _dataRepository = dataRepository;
        }

        // GET: api/Employee
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            IEnumerable<Employee> employees = _dataRepository.GetAll();
            return Ok(employees);
        }

        // GET: api/Employee/5
        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
        public IActionResult Get(long id)
        {
            Employee employee = _dataRepository.Get(id);

            if (employee == null)
            {
                return NotFound("The Employee record couldn't be found.");
            }

            return Ok(employee);
        }

        // POST: api/Employee
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Employee employee)
        {
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Employee is null.");
            }

            _dataRepository.Add(employee);
            return CreatedAtRoute(
                  "Get",
                  new { Id = employee.EmployeeId },
                  employee);
        }

        // PUT: api/Employee/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Put(long id, [FromBody] Employee employee)
        {
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Employee is null.");
            }

            Employee employeeToUpdate = _dataRepository.Get(id);
            if (employeeToUpdate == null)
            {
                return NotFound("The Employee record couldn't be found.");
            }

            _dataRepository.Update(employeeToUpdate, employee);
            return NoContent();
        }

        // DELETE: api/Employee/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Delete(long id)
        {
            Employee employee = _dataRepository.Get(id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return NotFound("The Employee record couldn't be found.");
            }

            _dataRepository.Delete(employee);
            return NoContent();
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone helps me id be very gratheful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the code in the question instead of using external links!

Comment: Dont post screenshots of errors. Post the actual text of the error so other people can find this post through google when they have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing [controller] to "Employee" in [Route("api/[controller]")]. Check this example from Microsoft [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#routing-and-url-paths)

> Replace [controller] with the name of the controller, which by convention is the controller class name minus the "Controller" suffix. For this sample, the controller class name is TodoItemsController, so the controller name is "TodoItems". ASP.NET Core routing is case insensitive.

Another option, check your Startup.cs file (post it here so we can check if everything is alright). And check this example explaining Attribute Route in .NET [Attribute Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: When link to an external resource you should try and copy some of the context into your post so it is not lost in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @MarkDavies. Is it okay now?